# MERN Stack with socket.io, io.on function fires twice when executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

In my application the io.on server side function executes the callback "emitter" 2x, I've read that when using npx create-react-app strick mode is automatically enabled and in development mode causes io.on to execute twice, the short answer was to remove React.StrickMode as a component in the index.js file on the client side. Strick was never in my code to begin with.

**Current execution logs "connected" 2 times server side,**

**Goal is for it to only log "connected" once on server side.**

Server Side:

app.js

```
//Listeners
import { emitter } from './sockets/emitter.js';

// App Config
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const server = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: 'http://localhost:3006' } });

// Middlewares
app.use(Cors());
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// Socket Emitter
io.on('connection', emitter);




// Listener
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on localhost: ${port}`));
```

emitter.js

```
export const emitter = (socket) => {
    try {
        
         console.log('connected');
         socket.emit('products:auction', { message: "Testing Server Side Error" });
                               
    } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
    };
};
```

Client Side:

index.js

```
import { reducers } from './reducers';

import App2 from './components/App2';


const store = createStore(reducers, {}, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App2 />
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

App2.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Landing from './Landing/Landing';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            user: 'new user'
        };
        
    };
    
    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({user: 'after mounted user'})
        
    }

    

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>                                                                                                                        
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact component={Landing} />                       
                </Switch>                                    
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    };
};

export default App;
```

Landing.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

import { CONNECTION_PORT } from '../../config';


// Socket Initialization
const socket = io(CONNECTION_PORT);



class Landing extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {            
            products: [],            
        };
    };
    
    componentDidMount() {
        socket.on("connect", () => {
            console.log('connected')    
        });
        socket.on('products:auction', (data) => {
                this.setState({ products: data.message });
        });                        
    };
           
    render() {
       
        return (
            <div> Testing Server Side Error </div>
        )    
    };
};

export default Landing;
```

Comment: Are you saying that you still get two ``"connected"`` logs, even though you don't have strict mode enabled?

Comment: That is what I believe is happening, however I am unsure... Can strick mode be enabled without it wrapping the app2 component? My problem is that in development I am querying and updating a few collections in my db in certain cases it is causing a lot of errors and can get overloaded which slows the performance of the app dramatically.